# Исходники openvpn для IOS

Tags: android, ios, opensource, openvpn

Подскажите, где скачать исходные коды openvpn для ОС Android и IOS? И в каких средах разработки их можно будет собрать.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри по этим ссылкам:

[OpenVPN for iPhone/iPad](https://code.google.com/p/guizmovpn/)

[With the new VPNService of Android API level 14+ (Ice Cream Sandwhich)](https://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/)